# SQL - Does not have a PK Key ERROR

Tags: sql, entity-framework, primary-key

Got an Excel file that contains nearly 10k rows.  I transferred it with a Codeplex Guide and created a new DB with a table that contains all data.
 When I use:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM RenewDatabase
```

It compiles and its soft clouds everywhere. When I add a ADO EF to my project, just for taking out all objects to a simple console application. I get the errorMessage:

> The table/view 'DBO' does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred. This table/view has been excluded. To use the entity, you will need to review your schema, add the correct keys, and uncomment it.

Well, I have tried a lot of different ways to configure this.  Now I have a table with a primary key that is the ProductID.  It is located as a PK in the "Keys" directory...

Trying to refresh, reconnect and all, but nothing changes. I still have the problem that the map over  my DB aint showing. Neither of my properties or columns is in the Visual Studios Data Model Designer.

Comment: Did you add a primary key to the `DBO` table?

Comment: "soft clouds everywhere" -- ah, lovely.

Comment: Drop the table from the designer (i.e. delete and ensure all related entity classes are gone) and re-add it.  If it *does* have the PK defined then it *should* recognise it after that

Answer (score 0):

DBO is usually the default database schema, not a table. Maybe your context has gotten confused somewhere?

Assuming this is a database-first approach (i.e. you have created an EDMX with the WYSIWYG editor), I would recommend you delete all your entities and re-import them. The database-first update wizard does not refresh renamed / re-defined relationships or columns (though it will add new ones), and it can be a bit confusing to sort them out manually, especially if you're not familiar with how DBMS's work.

Comment: Well, as always I am a bit disoriented when it comes to ask for a solution... Sorry if I wrote things that didnt was correct.
However, I have dropped, recreated and so on this table and created a new DB, with a new table "blahblah". So this was my last way out before i did shut down my comp.

It seems now that "the shut-down-part" did solve my problem. Dont know however if was the real solution... But as always, thank you Stackoverflow!